# T-SQL Picking up active IDs from a comma seperated IDs list

Tags: t-sql, filter, sql-server-2000

I have two tables "Product" having following structure:

```
ProductID,ProductName, IsSaleTypeA, IsSaleTypeB, IsSaleTypeC
1, AAA, N, N, N
2, BBB, N, Y, N  -- active 
3, CCC, N, N, N
4, DDD, Y, N, N  -- active
5, EEE, N, N, N
6, FFF, N, N, N
7, FFE, N, N, N
8, GGG, N, N, N
9, HHH, Y, N, N  -- active
```

The second table "ProductAllowed" has the following structure where ProductIDs is a comma separated string filed having mix of active and inactive product ids based on their `IsSaleType` mode.

```
ProductCode, ProductIDs
AMRLSPN, "1,2"
AMRLOFD, "1,3"
BLGHVF,  "2,4,6"
BLGHVO,  "2,4"
BLGHVD,  "3,5"
BLGSDO,  "0"
CHOHVF,  "1,6"
CHOHVP,  "1,2,7,8"
```

Is there a t-sql query that will return a list of active records from the "ProductAllowed" table if any of three IsSaleType fileds is/are switched on for a product?

Based on the sample data the ProductAllowed records should return following records:

```
AMRLSPN
BLGHVF
BLGHVO
BLGSDO
CHOHVP
```

This needs to be applied in a SQLSERVER 2000 database containing aprox 150000 records.

Comment: have you heard of first normal form?  Also, check out bit fields...

Comment: Sorry 1NF is not applicable in this case and can not change existing table structures due to impact on other systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this, but it goes something like this...

```
SELECT PRODUCTCODE
FROM
    ProductAllowed PA
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT CAST(ID AS varchar(10)) AS ProductID
    FROM PRODUCT WHERE
    IsSaleTypeA = 'Y' OR 
    IsSaleTypeB = 'Y' OR
    IsSaleTypeC = 'Y'
    ) P ON
           PA.ProductIDs LIKE '"P.ProductID,%' OR 
           PA.ProductIDs LIKE '%,P.ProductID"' OR 
           PA.ProductIDs LIKE '%,P.ProductID,%'
```